# correct pattern in flex, error : rule cannot me matched

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer

hello I'm trying to use the following pattern in flex to match information in the form of

- `ss:Name="string"` (the string has to be in "")
- `ss:Name="Number"` (the actual word Number)
- `ss:Workshop`

when I compile it it show warning errors that the rule cannot me matched. My code is this :

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
%}
%option noyywrap
letter [a-zA-Z]
digit [0-9]
other_characters [./-_]
whitespace [ \t]
newline [\n]
string ({letter}|{digit}|{other_characters})({letter}|{digit}|{other_characters})+
%%
{string}({whitespace}|{string})     {printf ("%s", yytext); return TEXTMSG;}
"ss\:Workshop"      {printf("%s", yytext); return WORKSHOP;}
"ss\:Name\=\"Number\""|"ss\:Name\="\"{string}\"|    {printf("%s", yytext); return NAME;}
```

Any clues as to why this is not ok? Kinda new to flex here so I believe I've missed something, not sure what though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this character class:

```
other_characters [./-_]
```

A dash in a character class indicates a range of possible characters (as in `[a-z]`, which matches any lower-case letter). So `/-_` matches any character whose codepoint is between `/` (0x2F) and `_` (0x5F) inclusive. That range includes digits, upper case letters, and some punctuation, including colon and semicolons.

That makes colon a valid character in a `{string}`, so `{string}` will match `ss:Workshop`. And since flex gives priority to the first rule which matches an input, that makes it impossible for the `ss:Workshop` rule to ever be matched.

You can fix that by putting the dash either at the beginning or the end of the character class: `[-./_]` or `[./_-]`. Those will just match one of the four characters listed.

By the way, there is no need to backslash-escape a colon, or even to quote it. It has no special significance in flex patterns.

Comment: Thanks for that! Seems to be fixed.